# I'm using firebase in my android project the "FirebaseRecyclerAdapter" is not coming with updated dependency I added old dependency but not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to retrieve data from Firebase for android. but it not work. please help me I am fully confused or suggest me easily understandable example. I'm at initial level. I view all code properly there is no one error. the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not comes with updated dependency.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
StorageReference storageReference ;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference_my;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    databaseReference_my= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference_my

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDetail(model.getTitle());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    View view;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view=itemView;
    }

    public  void setTitle(String title)
    {
        TextView put_title=view.findViewById(R.id.coming_title);
        put_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setDetail(String detail)
    {
        TextView put_detail=view.findViewById(R.id.coming_detail);
        put_detail.setText(detail);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you set `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: it is fixed because i use Row_layout.

Comment: at com.example.abbas.firebase1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)

Answer (score 0):

```
use following: build.gradle(app level)
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
```